# Sorting MPMediaQuery according to Playcount

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to do that since the past hour. I'm not sure what the problem is.
Here's my code:

```
NSArray *allTracks = [[[MPMediaQuery alloc] init] items] ;    
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [allTracks sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
   NSNumber *first = [(MPMediaItem*)a valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];
   NSNumber *second = [(MPMediaItem*)b valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];
    return [first compare:second]; 
}];
```

Comment: Can you provide an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [allTracks sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it works just fine.

`sortedArray` is sorted ascending according to the play count.

Maybe you have a huge iTunes library on your iPod? Maybe you have activated iTunes Match and not all data is on your phone?

Comment: Takes about 11 seconds for me to sort 10,000 songs.  I also use iTunes Match.